# evercookie no longer an "ever cookie"?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I was trying to implement the evercookie, which actually tries to save a cookie multiple ways (regular cookie, flash cookie, ...). According to information I find online this evercookie would make the cookie persistent, even if the user deletes his temporary internet files.

My tests show that this is not working at all. It turns out that when I remove my temporary internet files the evercookie is not being found when I re-visit the site...

Is evercookie supposed to still work?

Comment: most evercookie vectors have been closed via browser client security updates. plus, evercookies have no practical use whatsoever except privacy violations, so I advise you to stop trying to use them.

Comment: Evercookies are actually just you trying to force something down tyhe throat of your users which they don't want (if they clear cookies, they want to clear cookies, not something else). It's not exactly surprising that browsers are trying to stop them...

Comment: I wanted to implement it in order to detect users that we banned on our site who try to re-register.

Comment: so, right now, for the use I described in my previous comment, there's no single benefit in using evercookie instead of a regular cookie?

Comment: @Erik: There is no single benefit *to a legitimate site* in using evercookies.  Users don't just up and accidentally delete cookies; either they're running in a mode specifically designed to remove that stuff, or they are going into the browser's settings and actively choosing to do so.  If a user says "forget me" (by removing the info from the location(s) he expects it to be), any site that's worth a damn will honor that request, even if he didn't remove every trace.

Comment: @cHao I currently have a legitimate use: I'm writing a Javascript plugin that is to be used on multiple domains and needs to persist user logins across those domains, and hence I need to use third party cookies. However, some browsers like Safari now block third party cookies by default, and our users are not web-savvy enough to understand this and re-enable them. (Facebook apps using cookies face the same problem - since the cookies are all third party, the apps don't work on Safari.) Supercookies are the only way I can prevent Safari from breaking my plugin by default for ordinary users.

Comment: @cHao That said, I don't need the cookies to be undeletable - just to *actually set them* in spite of the browser's privacy settings (which, for the majority - probably all - of our users, were not set by the user themselves). The fact that this forces me to use methods that remove power users' ability to easily prevent the cookies from being stored, know that they are there, or remove them, is an unfortunate side effect that I would do something about if I could. Sadly, I don't know what we can do besides clearly signpost our use of supercookies in our privacy policy (which we will do).

Comment: @MarkAmery: Evercookies don't actually bypass privacy settings; *you can only set the cookie in the first place if the browser* (or Flash) *already let you do so.*  If the user doesn't have Flash installed (and thus doesn't support LSOs), for example, you're still screwed if that's the only mechanism that works with Safari.  So make it clear that you require certain features installed/enabled in order for stuff to work, and link to a page showing how to install/enable those features if your script can't do its job.

Comment: If you rely on supercookies/evercookies/etc, you're already going to have problems once the user gets a browser with finer-grained privacy controls.  The more sustainable solution is to help the users understand where/how/when to change their privacy settings; besides being more future-proof, it can even help fix the Safari problem to a degree.